# How to bulk insert in db if another insert succeeds?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, odbc

I have to insert `~40K records` in 2 tables(say table1 & table2) in the database.

The insert in table2 is conditional. A record should be inserted in table2 if and only if a record is inserted in table1 successfully.

Can this be done in batch? I'm using JDBC driver. I'm  using Oracle 10g XE.

What is the best approach to do this? Should I go for db pooling with multi-threading?

Comment: I would suggest you use the Oracle JDBC driver and use transactions ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html ) The insertion of the two records into the separate tables should be seen as one transaction. If the any insert fails, just roll back the whole transaction.
(Assuming that you always have to have _both_ records and failing to insert the second also have to be avoided.)

Comment: One way is to create sql procedure and execute it from java....

Comment: Why are you using the JDBC-ODBC bridge, when there is in Oracle JDBC driver that is far better?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I am using JDBC driver. It was a mistake on my part. Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: Define "Best" when you say best approach :)

Answer (score 0):

The executeUpdate method will return the number of rows affected by your statement. Could use this as a comparison to check it had executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is perform the business logic for the operation as close to the data as possible. This will mean having a PL/SQL procedure to act as an API for the functionality you wish to perform.

This will make your code trivial; a simple call to the database procedure which will return something giving you the result.

All the logic applied to the data is performed by code designed almost exclusively to manipulate data. Unlike Java which can manipulate data but not as well as PL/SQL. Incidentally it is also likely to be much faster.(this presentation on Youtube is very informative, if a little long - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jiJDflpw4Y )